# Can't use Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I have Windows on my machine and then I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using a CD. I couldn't select Ubuntu on startup, so I ran the boot-repair. Now I don't get the option to use Windows.

Any help here, please??

Answer (score 0):

from syg00 at http://www.linuxquestions.org/

> From the grub prompt you can enter the commands from your grub.conf.
>   Amend as appropriate, and hit enter after each line. Don't know that
>   you can run fixmbr from Windows, but this should get you there.

```
   root(hd0,0) <-- se this fits your needs (e.g., hd0,0 is the first partition of the primary master hard disk, hd3,1 is the second partition of the secondary slave hard disk)
   makeactive
   chainloader + 1
   boot
```

Comment: Grub legacy used hd0,0, but with grub2 partitions were changed to start with 1. IF Boot-Repair did not fix issue, then you may have a Windows issue?